# MVC 3 dynamic routing for hosted site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working on an MVC 3 site hosted by GoDaddy and I need to store dynamic variables in the URL. Something like:

`http://www.example.com/{Cat}/{List}/{Item}/{Action}` or
`http://{Cat}.example.com/{List}/{Item}/{Action}`

The latter would be the best.

The site allows users to create custom lists, list categories, and list items.  A list category could be something like `Sports` or `News`, a list could be `NBA Teams` or `Politics`, and a list item would be `Lakers` or `Pres. Obama`.  The user is able to generate any one of the 3 (only no duplicates).

My goal is to make the URL be something like `http://sports.example.com/nba/lakers` and have the user routed to `Controller = "Items", Action = "Details"`, with params `Cat = "sports", List = "nba", Item = "lakers"` and if the user specifies an `Action` (like Edit, Delete, etc), it replaces `Details`.

I'm not super familiar with IIS (more specifically IIS via GoDaddy), so IDK if the subdomaining would work (but that is the ultimate goal) and if it is possible, I'd like to know what I would need to do (i.e. self host + steps).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this section is a domain http://sports.example.com/ translating to physical address e.g. 203.10.01.1 you'll have to register a subdomains with GoDaddy. ASP.NET MVC will handle ... nba/lakers section. So your domain will be http://sportworldwide.com/ with subdomains like http://nba.sportworldwide.com/lakers. If want to use MVC 3 only. try something like

sportworldwide.com/sport/nba/lakers.

```
 routes.MapRoute("DefaultSport", "sport/{action}/{id}", 
                    new { controller = "Sport",  action = "", id= "" });
```

EDIT:

I can't comment too much on wildcard DNS records performance or etc. The only problem I see is you'll need to write a custom route handler, then you'll need to get the subdomain part of Url e.g. sport and change the action or id value to handle your subdomain urls.
here is example of modifying the route through a routehandler:
[asp.net MvcHandler.ProcessRequest is never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637295/asp-net-mvchandler-processrequest-is-never-called)

Comment: Thank you for the help :) If I self host the site (thus having total control over IIS), will that allow me to be more flexible over the subdomains?  Or are the subdomains handled outside of IIS (In one of the DNS servers or somewhere else)?  I've seen sites that have dynamic subdomains, so it must be possible, I just don't know how they do it!

Comment: well you'll need to look into ISAPI filter. here is an article about the pros and cons - where to get your hands on ISAPI rewrite filter. 
http://www.seoconsultants.com/windows/isapi/subdomains/
for IIS take a look at http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: what about a wildcard DNS record?  If I just added a wildcard DNS A Record and forwarded it to my site's IP, would that allow me to filter based on subdomain?

Comment: I can't comment too much on wildcard DNS records performance or etc. however you can definitely do that. The only problem I see is you'll need to write a custom route handler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206065/mvc-3-use-different-controllers-based-on-request-parameters  Then get front part of Url e.g. sport and change the action value or id handle your subdomain urls.